# PL/SQL, how to put common code lines of packages in a shared package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have several packages which some of their Specification and body lines are the same, so I would like to put all the same codes in a Common package and share that package in all. 
For procedures body, it was not so difficualt as I defined a Main procedure in my Common package and I used it in other packages, but how can I do the same for Specifications ?

suppose I have some common variable or constant variable:

```
CNST_S_DATA_MINIMA constant        varchar2 (10) := '1900-01-01';
CNST_D_DATA_MINIMA constant        date := To_date (CNST_S_DATA_MINIMA, CNST_S_FORMATO_DATE);
ERR__VOID_PARAMETER EXCEPTION;
```

Comment: What part of their specifications are same? Could you [edit] and add an example?

Comment: Please add some working example. Moreover, you don't use common packages to minimize just the number of lines. You use them to make a common functionality available for other package. PL/SQL is a full-fledged object oriented programming language. You have to make use of object oriented features for a better purpose than just saving the lines of code.

Comment: Could you make an example how to make use of Object oriented features?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put them into the package specification (not body) of a package that is used as the container for such global constants.

Comment: I know whatever I define in the package specification is Public, but  how the other packages know these varibales and constants have been defined without calling them one by one (pkg_A.variable1)? is there anyway to import a package in another one?

Comment: Not that I know of... but there is one thing you can do: define the constants in `PKG_B` like that: `CNST_S_DATA_MINIMA constant varchar2(10) := PKG_A.CNST_S_DATA_MINIMA;`; so you have just one place where the real values are (DRY).

Comment: but this means writting the same number of lines I had before in my packages, while the main reason I wanted to have a Common_PKG was to seperate repeated lines and to minimize number of lines!

Comment: Actually pkg_b does not need to define a variable that equals a value from pkg_a.  Just reference the pkg_a value directly when you need it. Just keep in mind variables defined in the package spec are public and available to programs outside of the package, variables defined in the package body are private and available to functions/procedure within the package only. Note you can define a private function/procedure in the body too that is only visible to package members.

Comment: @Gary_W: If the package body contains numerous references to a variable, the cross-referencing trick might reduce the effort.

Comment: @Alex: You still have the same number of lines, that's true, but you have a single place where the values are defined. That's worth a lot, since you only have to change a definition in one place.